# What Win32 message is sent to window at the beginning of resize?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need Win32 analog of C#'s `ResizeBegin` to store some data before receiving the first `WM_SIZE`. I believe I used it very long ago, but cannot find any reference.
For some weird reason, Spy++ on my computer is not operational (both 64- and 32-bit versions, I will deal with them later). I hope, somebody can help me out, thanks in advance!

It looks like it is WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, at least, it is sent at the right moment. Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: [`WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-entersizemove).

Comment: Yes! Thanks! While poking around, I realized, that I can pack everything in WM_SIZE handler, but this is just for now. I will sure need it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`WM_SIZING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-sizing) message.

Comment: Checked out, both WM_SIZING and WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING are sent continuously, must be something else. When I resize a window, typically SIZING, WINDOWPOSCHANGING, and SIZE are repeating. At the beginning and at the end they are sent out of sequence. Theoretically, I can associate them with mouse message, unless there is something better. Thanks!

Comment: Yes they are sent out continuously, isn't that what you want? A message that's sent before the size change happens, with the new size information?

Comment: Actually I need to store some settings before the tracking starts, and use them during the tracking. I have this functionality in C# program, trying to make similar thing in C++. WM_SIZING precedes WM_SIZE, it may work, will find out.

Comment: You are a genius! I didn't realize, that I can capture what I need within the same WM_SIZE handler, I don't need other messages. In C#, resizing was automatically done by anchoring and I didn't realize, that in C++ I am resizing controls myself - and I can retrieve what I need before calling MoveWindow, and put it back after MoveWindow, all inside the same handler. Way better than saving the stuff off before resize. Thanks!

Comment: I think WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE is the answer to the question that was asked